# Copying files via command in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I am already aware of the `cp` command.

Here's my goal:

I have a USB flash drive with some music on it, for example. Along with a full system backup, I keep some photos, music, etc. on a separate drive. Is there a command with which I can only copy files which are not already contained on the drive? (So I don't have to delete everything and/or copy all the new files manually)

E.g. I have a "file x" on my drive and computer, but only "file y" on my computer, which I want to copy to the drive; can I only copy file y to the drive without copying x too? (Obviously assuming there's more than 1 file)

Let me know if my wording is confusing, and I'll try and explain better.

Comment: This could help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/538913/how-can-i-copy-files-with-duplicate-filenames-into-one-directory-and-retain-both