# Copying and Renaming folders incrementally

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a folder called P1. How can I make 59 copies of that folder but naming them incrementally, i.e., the new folders are named as P2,P3,...,P60?

Here's what I did, but it didn't work:
I made 59 copies manually and then tried to rename them using:

```
j=2;for f in /path/to/folders/*; do mv "$f" "$j"; let j=j+1; done
```

but instead all of my copied files including the original file were deleted from the directory.

What was wrong with the command I wrote and how I can do all the copying and renaming automatically?

Comment: similar but not exact duplicated of [How can I copy files with duplicate filenames into one directory and retain both files by having the duplicate(s) rename automatically?](http://askubuntu.com/q/538913/283843)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your command, the directories are first renamed to the value of var `j` which is `2`, so you end up with only one copy named `2` (as each overwrites the previous one). After that process has completed, `j` is reassigned to `j+1` (`echo $j` returns `3`) - it doesn't increment.

To make 59 copies you can do this:

```
for i in {2..60}; do cp -r -- P1 P"$i"; done
```

`{2..60}` expands to 2 3 4 5 6 7 all the way to 60

For fixed width numbers (so 02 comes before 11 when sorting) use `printf`:

```
for i in {2..60}; do cp -r -- P1 P$(printf %02d "$i"); done
```

This gives `P02` `P03` `P04`... `P10`, `P11`

---

For incremental renaming you might do something like this, assuming the copies aren't numbered...

```
j=0; for dir in /path/to/stuff/*; do mv -v -- "$dir" "$dir""$((++j))"; done
```

Fixed width format:

```
j=0; for dir in /path/to/stuff/*; do printf -v new "$dir%02d" "$((++j))"; mv -v -- "$dir" "$new"; done
```

Maybe worth making that last one more readable...

```
j=0
for dir in /where/my/stuff/is/*
  do printf -v new "$dir%02d" "$((++j))"
  mv -v -- "$dir" "$new"
done
```